# SaveFileDialog doesn't show in new thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, dialog

I've been confused by this problem for a very long time. I start the new thread by using System.Threading, just like this:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart threadFileExport = FileExport;
Thread threadExport = new Thread(threadFileExport)
{
    IsBackground = true,
    Name = "threadExport",
    Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
};
threadExport.Start(_dataTable);
```

and

```
public void FileExport(object objTable)
{

     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
     {
         DefaultExt = "xlsx",
         Filter = "Excel 2007-2010|*.xlsx|" +
                  "Excel95,97,2003|*.xls|",
         FileName = "table.xlsx",
         Title = "Save as. . ."
     };
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

But the dialog won't show and it seems that the thread will abort immediately when executing "ShowDialog". Is this a bug or I made a mistake? Can a background thread shows a savefile dialog?

Comment: You need to invoke it, using invoke will allow it to show on the gui thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a dialog must be shown on the UI thread, just as any other UI operation.

Comment: thank you for answering. Could you tell me how to notify the UI thread in the end of the new thread, so that the UI thread can go on to show the dialog?

Comment: @wings: You can use `Invoke()` to call afunction on the UI thread. Or you may put your background work in a `BackgroundWorker` and show the dialog in its `RunWorkerCompleted` delegate. See the docs for examples of those methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your answer is likely to solve my problem. I'll try later~

Comment: I have solved the problem, thank you~

`ParameterizedThreadStart tsFileExport = FileExport;`

`Thread threadExport = new Thread(tsFileExport);`

`threadExport.Start(_dataTable);`

and in the end of the new thread:

`Invoke(new MainThreadInvokerDelegate(SaveAs), new object[] { worksheet, workbook, excelApp }
                );`


and thank you for your answers, too~ @henginy

Answer (score 2):

The thread you created doesn't establish a message loop, so you cannot show it.

Better is to ask user the file path on the UI thread and then start your export thread, passing it the file name. Still better is using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) thread so that your UI remains responsive.

**Update:**
If you cannot use BackgroundWorker, below is the code for the alternative I described.
I assume you have a method similar to `ExportDataTableToFile` which you call after you get the file name.

```
//
// Assuming your actual export method is similar to this:    
//
void ExportDataTableToFile(DataTable dataTable, string fileName) {
    // ...
}
```

And I assume you're on the UI thread here:

```
//
// You can ask for the file path first;
//
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
{
     DefaultExt = "xlsx",
     Filter = "Excel 2007-2010|*.xlsx|" +
              "Excel95,97,2003|*.xls|",
     FileName = "table.xlsx",
     Title = "Save as. . ."
};
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();


string fileName = null;
if(saveFileDialog.Result == DialogResult.OK) // "else" case should be added
    fileName = saveFileDialog;

//
// And then start the thread:
//
Thread threadExport = new Thread(() => ExportDataTableToFile(_dataTable, fileName))
{
    IsBackground = true,
    Name = "threadExport",
    Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
};
threadExport.Start();
```

Comment: thank you. But...in fact, the program I am writing is more complicatd, so I have to give up using BackgroundWorker.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

try this

in your class

```
private object sync_temp = new object();
```

and in thread method

```
string path;
SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
// your code to do with "save"
Action ac = () => { lock (sync_temp) { save.ShowDialog(); } };
Invoke(ac);
lock (sync_temp)
{
   path = save.FileName;
}
```

or mark that thread as STAThread